# Using FFT to compute DFT of a polynomial

Tags: algorithms, fourier-analysis, recursive-algorithms

i currently studying about FFT and DFT and we were given simple question:
Use the recursive FFT to compute the DFT of this polynomial of '3' degree: $$-1\:+\:4x\:+\:3x^2$$.

So, i go to this algorithm:
[image]

But i don't understand what happens in line **11**.
What is $y_k^0$? and $y_k^1$?

Can someone guide me in the intermediate steps? i get stuck when i get that $y^{\left[0\right]}\:=\:\left(-1\right)$ and that $y^{\left[1\right]}\:=\:\left(3\right)$

tnx so much!